# How to make it so when I run my script it will not run again for the day and will change another item on the page

Tags: javascript

Okay the questions are. I need help on making it so when I click the button it runs the free_cash variable in the function which I have set up. But I want it to add the givin amount to the total money the person has.

I also want to know how I can make it so when you click the button to get your free daily cash it only allows you to do it once a day and if you click it more the message switches to Something like you already been givin a handout today.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Character
</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p style="margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; color: darkblue; font-size: 35px;">Money:</p>
<button onclick="FreeCash()">Free Daily Cash</button><br>
<p id="freecash"></p>

<script>
    function FreeCash(){
    var free_cash = "Someone handed you \"$100\" You must be a lucky man";
    var nofree_cash = "Sorry you already got your handout for the day. Come back tomorrow ight.";
    document.getElementById("freecash").innerHTML = free_cash;
    }
</script>

<br><br><br><br>

<noscript>
    <h3>This site requires JavaScript</h3>
</noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you're doing it client side only then you will need to use cookies to track it between page loads. if you have access to something server side then you can keep track of it there and it will be a little more secure.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
function FreeCash() {
    //Checks whether lastDate has been set.
    if (!!localStorage.getItem("lastDate")) {
        //If so and a day did not pass since then, then end the function
        if ((new Date() - new Date(localStorage.getItem("lastDate"))) / (1000 * 3600 * 24) < 1) {
            return;
        }
    }
    //Set last date to current moment. You can set it to 00:00:00 of the day as well, if that fulfills your requirements better.
    localStorage.setItem("lastDate", new Date());
    var free_cash = "Someone handed you \"$100\" You must be a lucky man";
    var nofree_cash = "Sorry you already got your handout for the day. Come back tomorrow ight.";
    document.getElementById("freecash").innerHTML = free_cash;
}
```

This should solve the problem on client-side even if the user navigates off the page, however, you need a validation at server-side as well, because I could modify your client-side functions in my browser console whenever I want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to check if the button was clicked :

```
var clicked = false;
function FreeCash(){
    var free_cash = "Someone handed you \"$100\" You must be a lucky man";
    var nofree_cash = "Sorry you already got your handout for the day. Come back tomorrow ight.";
    if(!clicked) {
        document.getElementById("freecash").innerHTML = free_cash;
        clicked = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("freecash").innerHTML = nofree_cash;
    }
}
```

You can see the **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/0awauh0d/)**.

**EDIT:**

And to make it available once a day you could use a `setInterval()` to reset the value of `clicked` to `false` after a day.

```
setInterval(function(){
              clicked = false; 
            }, 1000*60*60*24); // after a day
```

It's a dirty way but it should do the trick.

You can see the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0awauh0d/2/)** wich executes every 10 seconds.

Comment: From OP post: "*I also want to know how I can make it so when you click the button to get your free daily cash **it only allows you to do it once a day** and if you click it more the message switches to Something like you already been given a handout today*"

Comment: @PM I missed that part, but what about the approach in  my EDIT.

Comment: Your approach is not realistic. For it to work a user should keep his/her browser open and connected to this website 24/7. We are not dealing with server-side script here.

Comment: @Joshua You need to have a server side code that handles this situation.

Answer (score 0):

*You cannot do this with only javascript*.... you need a database to store the time when your user clicked, tough a web side language (PHP, Java EE....ect).

Comment: You can do it with JS for users that allow cookies.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var givenDateTime = new Date();
    var isGiven = false;
    function FreeCash(){

    var cuurDateTime = new Date();

    var message = '';
    var free_cash = "Someone handed you \"$100\" You must be a lucky man";
    var nofree_cash = "Sorry you already got your handout for the day. Come back tomorrow ight.";
    alert(isGiven);
    alert((cuurDateTime.getDate() - 1) < givenDateTime);
    if(isGiven && (cuurDateTime.getDate() - 1) < givenDateTime){
        message=nofree_cash;
        document.getElementById("freecash").innerHTML = message;
    }else{
        message=free_cash;
        isGiven = true;
        givenDateTime = new Date();
        document.getElementById("freecash").innerHTML = message;
    }


    }
```

Comment: @Joshua you must have to go for php perl or other server side language to make a concret solution, even you can not achieve by using HTML5 or by WEBSQL and it can be change by client.